# Can't connect through tableau on EC2 using https

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, tableau-api, terraform-provider-aws

I am running `tableau server 2021-1-2` on `EC2` instance.
I can connect using the default public ip on port `80`, also on port `8050` for the `Tableau TSM UI`. And the same using the hostname I defined. The only issue I have is despite following several guidelines I can't connect using https.

I setup the ports on the security-group, the load-balancer, the certificate, i waited for hours as I saw that the ssl certificate could take more than half of an hour and nothing.

I can connect using:

```
http://my_domain.domain
```

But not:

```
https://my_domain.domain
```

I receive the following error in the browser: Can't connect to the server `https://my_domain.domain`.

I run `curl -i https://my_domain.domain`
It returns:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my_domain.domainport 443: Connection refused
```

The security group of my instance has the following ports (u can see it in tf too):

[image]

Here you have my tf setup.

I did the `EC2` setup with:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tableau" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = var.key_name
  subnet_id = compact(split(",", var.public_subnets))[0]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.tableau-sg.id]

  root_block_device{
    volume_size = var.volume_size
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.namespace
  }
}
```

I created the load balancer setup using:

```
resource "aws_lb" "tableau-lb" {
  name = "${var.namespace}-alb"

  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = false

  subnets         = compact(split(",", var.public_subnets))
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.tableau-sg.id]

  ip_address_type = "ipv4"

  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = true

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  idle_timeout = 300
}


resource "aws_alb_listener" "https" {
  depends_on        = [aws_alb_target_group.target-group]
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.tableau-lb.arn

  protocol = "HTTPS"
  port     = "443"

  ssl_policy      = "my_ssl_policy"
  certificate_arn = "arn:xxxx"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.target-group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_action.0.target_group_arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "target-group" {
  name = "${var.namespace}-group"

  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "instance"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
    timeout             = var.health_check_timeout
    interval            = var.health_check_interval
    path                = var.path
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.namespace
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb.tableau-lb]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tableau-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.target-group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.tableau.id
  port             = 80
}
```

The security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "tableau-sg" {
  name_prefix = "${var.namespace}-sg"

  tags = {
    Name = var.namespace
  }

  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  # HTTP from the load balancer
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # HTTP from the load balancer
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8850
    to_port     = 8850
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # HTTP from the load balancer
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # 443 secure access from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # Outbound internet access
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Also setup a hostname domain using:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "tableau-record-dns" {
  zone_id = var.route_53_zone_id
  name    = "example.hostname"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [aws_instance.tableau.public_ip]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "tableau-record-dns-https" {
  zone_id = var.route_53_zone_id
  name    = "asdf.example.hostname"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["asdf.acm-validations.aws."]
}
```

Comment: " I can't connect using https" is not specific. What exactly is happening? How do you test it? What are error msgs? What about http access using your domain?

Comment: @Marcin http access using the domain is working fine as I said in the post. I receive Can' connect on the browser when trying https. I test it with the browser itself

Comment: Can you run `curl -i https://my_domain.domain`?

Comment: @Marcin Done. It retunrs: curl: (7) Failed to connect to my_domain.domainport 443: Connection refused

I updated the post with the test and the result, adn the security groups ports. I have 443 open, so i dont know why it is refused.

Comment: So can you explain your records? What is `records = ["asdf.acm-validations.aws."]`? Where is the alias record to your ALB?

Comment: This one is the CNAME record that Certificate manager ask me to create in the route 53 to be able to validate the certificate. In AWS Certifcate manager i see the certificate as validated and released, so everything green.

The tableau-record-dns is the one that redirects from my instance ip to the hostname. Which i assume is working fine as hostname without https is working

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue, it was related to the record A. I was assignin an ip there an its impossible to redirect to an specific ip with the loadbalancer there. I redirect traffic to an `ELB` and worked fine